# Excel vba if the statements and auto update

Tags: vba, excel

im looking for some basic help with VBA. I have created a userform for fellow members to fill out information when we go on a call. When ok is pressed, the data is sent to sheet2 and laid in the next open row. In sheet 3 i have the printable form of the userform that i made out. I am trying to write the vba code in the printable form, so when the call # changes in cell b2, it will automatically change all other cells in that form, with the corresponding data in the same row from sheet 2.

Im new to the forum so im not sure how to upload etc. but i will try and give an example below.

Sheet2 looks something like this, for the example each cell seperated by "."

18-170001.01/02/17.Accident."current address"."call info"

18-170002.01/02/17.Training."current address"."call info"

in sheet4 this is the code i am using and it is not working

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 5 To Row.Count

        If sheet4 .cells(b2).value=sheet2.Cells(i,1).value then
            sheet4.cells(e2).value=sheet2.cells(i,1).value

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

I would add additional if then statments for each cell in sheet 4 to match each cell in sheet 2.

Please any help is appreciated

Comment: @YowE3K 's suggestion to use VLOOKUPs on your Print sheet, be it Sheet3 or Sheet4 is a better solution than using VBA.  That way if anyone move cells on your Print sheet, you (or they) won't have to remember to edit the code.  Another user may not even be aware of the code.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald - I wish I could upvote your comment about 10 times!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Cells(b2)`, it needs to be `Range("B2")` or `Cells(2, "B")` or `Cells(2, 2)`.

So your code could be:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 5 To Row.Count

        If sheet4.cells(2, "B").value=sheet2.Cells(i,1).value then
            sheet4.cells(2, "E").value=sheet2.cells(i,1).value

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

But you would be better off just using a formula for this purpose instead.  For example, the above code could be replaced by having the following formula in cell E2 of `sheet4`:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE)
```

(That assumes that `sheet2` has a sheet name of "Sheet2".)